# What is the purpose of @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I'm using CRA - I discovered [@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source), but it doesn't output a `__source` prop or attribute for me. What does this plugin do? Is it just used internally by the react debugging extension for chrome?

Comment: I cannot get this plugin to work with latest Create-React-App (v3). I inspect dom/elements and inspect props with react dev tools, and can't find anything. Therefore have to resort to adding special debugging classes to divs.